# need help in php generating HTML

Tags: php

I was learning to validate form data. When I had to write this:

```
"<"form method="post" action=""<"php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

but when I write this, in output, there is a `">` showing at the top of the page. Why?

Comment: When you have a problem with what the browser is rendering, look first at the HTML — **not** the PHP which generates it — and use [a markup validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: here is my full html file:

Comment: <html> 
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
Website: <input type="text" name="website">
Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
Gender:
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @RedwanulSourav use that HTML as your PHP code and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, there is an `echo` or a `print`.Change this:

```
echo "form method="post" action=""<"php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"
```

to this:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '">';
```